# app crashes when releasing appDelegate instance

Tags: iphone

i have this code that passes the core data context to one of the controllers.
it was working great for few days, until the debugger started to give me the "not A type release" error and crashing the app.
i have checked the app for leaks and i found leaks from the SappDelegate object. so i understand that i have to release it but it keeping crashing every time i do it.

any ideas
thanks
shani

```
SAppDelegate *hbad= [[SAppDelegate alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [hbad managedObjectContext];
[hbad release];
if (!context) {
    NSLog(@"problem with mannaged");
}
self.managedObjectContext = context;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SAppDelegate is your actual app delegate, that is not the correct way to get it. you should change your code to:

```
SAppDelegate *hbad= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [hbad managedObjectContext];
if (!context) {
    NSLog(@"problem with mannaged");
}
self.managedObjectContext = context;
```

Also, leaks will not cause crashes until MUCH later when your application runs out of memory and the system kills it.

Comment: hi Elfred.

worked perfectly 
is this always the way to communicate with the app delegate?

im happy to tell you that you have just helped me finnish my first app.
working great no leaks..

great day to you all

Comment: Yes, If you ever need to get an instance of the app delegate, that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you're creating a new SAppDelegate. You should only have one of these and it gets created for you on startup. Why do you need another SAppDelegate instance?

You should see [Elfred's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974528/app-crashes-when-releasing-appdelegate-instance/2974591#2974591) to get the app delegate instead of creating one.

---

However, there is one bug in the code you have posted . . .

You need to retain the context until you're done with it. Either :

```
SAppDelegate *hbad= [[SAppDelegate alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[hbad managedObjectContext] retain];
[hbad release];
if (!context) {
    NSLog(@"problem with mannaged");
}
self.managedObjectContext = context;
[context release];
```

or release hbad later on :

```
SAppDelegate *hbad= [[SAppDelegate alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [hbad managedObjectContext];
if (!context) {
    NSLog(@"problem with mannaged");
}
self.managedObjectContext = context;
[hbad release];
```

Comment: hi
thanks for the quick reply

1. i have to pass the ManagedObjectContext that is stored in the app delegate, thats why im creating it again. if there something rong with doing that? or a better way i would love to know how.

2. i tried your suggestions but i steel have the same crash log.

thans again


shani

Comment: Hi, Elfred's answer is better than mine - it show's how to get the app delegate that already exists instead of using a new one :)